# Aggregate two different types of records in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I have a specific task to join two data streams in one aggregation using `Apache Flink` with some additional logic.

Basically I have two data streams: a stream of events and a stream of so-called `meta-events`. I use `Apache Kafka` as a message backbone. What I'm trying to achieve is to trigger the `aggregation/window` to the evaluation based on the information given in `meta-event`. The basic scenario is:

1. The Data Stream of events starts to emit records of `Type A`;
2. The records keep accumulating in some aggregation or window based on some key;
3. The Data Stream of meta-events receives a new `meta-event` with the given key which also defines a total amount of the events that will be emitted in the Data Stream of events.
4. The number of events form the step `3` becomes a trigger criteria for the aggregation. After a total count of `Type A` events with a given key becomes equal to the number defined in the `meta-event` with a given key the aggregation should be triggered to the evaluation.

Steps `1` and `3` occur in the non-deterministic order, so they can be reordered.

What I've tried is to analyze the `Flink Global Windows` but not sure whether it would be a good and adequate solution. I'm also not sure if such problem has a solution in `Apache Flink`.

Any possible help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplistic answer is to `.connect()` the two streams, `keyBy()` the appropriate fields in each stream, and then run them into a custom `KeyedCoProcessFunction`. You'd save the current aggregation result & count in the left hand (`Type A`) stream state, and the target count in the right hand (`meta-event`) stream state, and generate results when the aggregation count == the target count.

But there is an issue here - what happens if you get N records in the `Type A` stream before you get the `meta-event` record for that key, and N > the target count? Essentially you either have to guarantee that doesn't happen, or you need to buffer `Type A` events (in state) until you get the `meta-event` record.

Though similar situations could occur if the `meta-event` target can be changed to a smaller value, of course.

Comment: Hi @kkruglet, thank you! In my case the equality of the target number of events in `meta` is guaranteed.